# No module named 'pyautogui'

Tags: python-3.x, import, visual-studio-2019, pyautogui

i am using pyautogui for a bot on python 3.7. In the very first line it imports pyautogui
`import pyautogui` and when i run it it says `No module named 'pyautogui'` , I tried it with a version of it for 3.7 and 3.8 and upgrading it (because it might have been the cause). I am coding on MS visual studio 2019 and i tried it on 3.7 for 32-bit and 64-bit (none of that seemed to help). Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

### For VS 2019 installs:

This artical details how to install it correctly
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/tutorial-working-with-python-in-visual-studio-step-05-installing-packages?view=vs-2019

### For non Visual Studio installs

You will need to install pyautogui with pip.

In the command line run

`pip install pyautogui`

You can find the install docs for pyautogui here: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Comment: can you run `py --list` to list the versions of python you have installed

Comment: well, it does show that i have 3.7-64 and 3.7-32 and a star at the 3.7-64 one

Comment: run `py -3.7-32 -m pip install pyautogui` to install it into the other version of python as well and try to re run

Comment: did that. now what?

Comment: Follow these steps to install pyautogui into vs 2019. VS 2019 packages their own version of python internally
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/tutorial-working-with-python-in-visual-studio-step-05-installing-packages?view=vs-2019